# What is IndexRegionSplitPolicy?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop2

Javadoc contains a single line explanation which I am unable to understand. "Split policy for index regions to avoid split from external requests". Can somebody please elaborate it.

http://javadox.com/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-core/4.7.0-HBase-1.1/org/apache/phoenix/hbase/index/IndexRegionSplitPolicy.html